# Which is the TComponentEditor for TFDQuery?

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

I needed to add a new option on the contextual menu of our custom TFDQuery, so I followed this guide and it works nicely. [How to add context-menu actions in Delphi Form Designer for a custom component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786204/how-to-add-context-menu-actions-in-delphi-form-designer-for-a-custom-component)

The problem is that it replaces the current TComponentEditor for the TFDQuery, so I can no longer access to its Fields Editor, Query Editor, ...

I guess what I need is to derive my TComponentEditor from the FireDAC base TComponentEditor, but I haven't been able to identify it. Can you, please, address me to the Unit and class that declares the regular TComponentEditor for a TFDQuery ?.

**Update:**  I have added this code to my custom Query to get the current ComponentEditor for TFDQuery, it says TFDQueryEditor in the FireDAC.dcl.Reg unit. But my system doesn't have any FireDAC.Dcl.Reg.pas, nor I can find any reference to TFDQueryEditor to the FireDAC source code.

```
constructor TKpQuery.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  ShowMessage(  (GetComponentEditor(Self, NIL) as TObject).ClassName  );
  ShowMessage(  (GetComponentEditor(Self, NIL) as TObject).UnitName  );
end;
```

This is my custom ComponentEditor:

```
interface

uses System.Classes, DesignIntf, DesignEditors, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

type
{$REGION 'TKpQuery Editor Declaration'}
  TKpQueryEditor=class(TComponentEditor)
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
  end;
{$ENDREGION}

{$REGION 'TKpQuery Declaration'}
  ...
  ...
{$ENDREGION}

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Data.DB,
  System.Types,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.StrUtils,
  System.RegularExpressions;

procedure Register;
begin
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  RegisterComponents('My Custom Data Access', [TKpQuery]);
  RegisterComponentEditor(TKpQuery, TKpQueryEditor);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

{$REGION 'TKpQuery Editor Implementation'}
procedure TKpQueryEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  case Index of
    0: (Component as TKpQuery).SetDisplayLabels;  
  end;
end;

function TKpQueryEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: Result := 'Set DisplayLabels';  
  end;
end;

function TKpQueryEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;   
end;
{$ENDREGION}
```

Comment: Have a look at: [Can I add a second component editor to a component in Firemonkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877067/can-i-add-a-second-component-editor-to-a-component-in-firemonkey)

Comment: Thanks @BlurrySterk, I have seen the solution that was proposed there, but it seems overly complicated to me. Why haven't they just derived from the current ComponentEditor instead of creating a new blank ComponentEditor and calling the previous Editor class for that component on every method ?. If I knew what class do I have to derive (its current ComponentEditor) then I believe my customized ComponentEditor would be much simpler.

Comment: You can also look at the `TADODatasetEditor` which derives from `TDatasetEditor` and see how that is done aspecially with regards to the `Index` parameters. That is in the `ADOReg` unit. The `TDatasetEditor` seems to be the one handling the **_Fields Editor_** option on the context menu

Comment: If you add dclFireDAC to the requires of your design package, you should be able to add FireDAC.dcl.reg to the uses clause. That way you can derive from TFDQueryEditor.

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe, as always, you are a life saver.

Comment: Sorry that I insist @UweRaabe, but where is the dclFireDAC.dcp supposed to be ?.  I have a dclFireDAC280.bpl on my Delphi bin folder, but I can't find the dclFireDAC.dcp anywhere (the closest I can see is the dclFireDACEntExt.dcp).

Comment: It is indeed missing. I'm unsure if this is an oversight or not. Then you are probably forced to go the complicated route.

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe, then I will replicate the solution on Blurry Sterk's link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Uwe Raabe has confirmed that the unit needed to derive the FDQuery Component Editor is not available, I've replicated the solution that Blurry Sterk suggested.

This seems to work fine:

```
unit MyCustom.Query.Editor;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, DesignIntf, DesignEditors;

  type
  TgkQueryEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
  private
    FOldEditor: IComponentEditor;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner); override;
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
    procedure Edit; override;
    procedure Copy; override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  MyCustom.Query;

var
  PrevEditorClass: TComponentEditorClass = nil;

constructor TgkQueryEditor.Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner);
begin
  inherited Create(AComponent, ADesigner);

  if Assigned(PrevEditorClass) then
    FOldEditor := TComponentEditor(PrevEditorClass.Create(AComponent, ADesigner));
end;

procedure TgkQueryEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := Index - FOldEditor.GetVerbCount;
  case i of
    0: (Component as TKpQuery).SetDisplayLabels;  // This is my new custom action
  else
    if Assigned(FOldEditor) then
      FOldEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index)
  end;
end;

function TgkQueryEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := Index - FOldEditor.GetVerbCount;
  case i of
    0: Result := 'Set Display Label';
  else
    if Assigned(FOldEditor) then
      Result := FOldEditor.GetVerb(Index)
  end;
end;

function TgkQueryEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
  if Assigned(FOldEditor) then
    Inc(Result, FOldEditor.GetVerbCount);
end;

procedure TgkQueryEditor.Edit;
begin
  if Assigned(FOldEditor) then
    FOldEditor.Edit;
end;

procedure TgkQueryEditor.Copy;
begin
  if Assigned(FOldEditor) then
    FOldEditor.Copy;
end;

procedure Register;
var
  Query: TKpQuery;
  Editor: IComponentEditor;
begin
  Query := TKpQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    Editor := GetComponentEditor(Query, nil);
    if Assigned(Editor) then
      PrevEditorClass := TComponentEditorClass((Editor as TObject).ClassType);
  finally
    Editor := nil;
    FreeAndNIL(Query);
  end;
  RegisterComponentEditor(TKpQuery, TgkQueryEditor);
end;

end.
```